# How to test if all fields of a bit mark are present in another bit mask?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, c, ipad

For example if you have bit masks of type UIUserNotificationType and you construct them like this:

```
UIUserNotificationType a = UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge;
UIUserNotificationType b = UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationType c = UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound;
```

How do you match one against another to see wether ALL fields are contained within the other?

`b` is fully included in `a` and should result in TRUE.
`c` is NOT fully included in `a` and should result in FALSE.

I know how to test membership for one particular field:
BOOL match = (b & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) != 0;

This does not work:

```
BOOL included = (a & b); // a includes b? (= YES)
included = (a & c); // a includes c? (= YES)
```

To know if ALL fields of one bit mask are included in another I would have to create an `if` for every possible field and test against it like so:

```
if (b & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert && !(a & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)) {
    return NO;
}
if (b & UIUserNotificationTypeBadge && !(a & UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)) {
    return NO;
}
if (b & UIUserNotificationTypeSound && !(a & UIUserNotificationTypeSound)) {
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

This feels wrong. There ought to be a simpler way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To test if mask `b` is completely included in mask `a`, you may try `bitwise and`:

```
if((b & a) == b)
```